# Extract top N count from data frame with column showing count while maintaining data frame structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following:

```
c1 <- c(324, 213, 122, 34)
c2 <- c("SDOIHHFOEKN", "SDIUFONBSD", "DSLIHFEIHDFS", "DOOIUDBD")
c3 <- c("G", "T", "U", "T")

df <- data.frame(count = c1, seq = c2, other = c3)
```

I want the top N sequences in a data frame. For example, for N = 600, I want the final data frame to have a column sum of count to be 600, meaning that only the top 3 rows of this data frame would remain, and the count of the third row would now be 600-324-213 = 63.

How can I get the output data frame like this?

I would really appreciate it if you could provide a general solution, as the data frame I am working with has over 1000 rows and smaller numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). The idea is to arrange the data frame by `count` by descending order, subset for the first three rows, and then update the `count` column with the last row to be 600 minus all the count of previous row. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  arrange(desc(c1)) %>%
  slice(1:which(cumsum(c1) > 600)[1])) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 
                        600 - sum(count[1:(n() - 1)]),
                        count))
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   count seq          other
#   <dbl> <fct>        <fct>
# 1 324   SDOIHHFOEKN  G    
# 2 213   SDIUFONBSD   T    
# 3  63.0 DSLIHFEIHDFS U
```

Comment: Never mind, I think I figured it out. I replaced 1:3 with `1:which(cumsum(c1) > 600)[1])` Thanks!